# Do popular applications use sockets to communicate with server or other clients?

Tags: sockets, architecture, network-programming

I recently coded a simple program that uses sockets to communicate for a synchronization of two clients. Then I'm wondering now if popular applications such as game agents(ex. the League of Legends game client, Steam game manager agent, etc...), streaming services(ex. youtube, twitch...), os update agents(windows, linux, mac os...) and so on are using sockets at the very bottom of whole communication among computers, or else there are proprietary architectures that are used only for those applications' communications respectively.

- if those popular applications use sockets basically, please recommend books that tell about the architecture of programs using sockets with somehow reliable structure(that is, programs that can handle the broken pipe problem and other well known problems for sockets).

Thanks in advance for all answers!

Comment: Please take some time to read or refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Try not to ask for book recommendations or general learning.  To answer your question though, yes, anything that uses IP protocols (the internet) ultimately uses sockets.  Most developers use higher-level abstractions like HTTP to simply their lives and handle most of the plumbing.